# AND and OR in my CPT search query depending on checkbox

Tags: php, wp-query

I have a checkbox, that when checked is supposed to change a query from `AND` to `OR`. The moods, genres and the checkbox data comes through just fine via a ajax call, and based on this, it will filter a list I've made. It works smooth, besides my if/else statement in my function below don't act as expected.

I currently can't figure a pattern in it's behavior, but I can in my error log spot an error. Note how both `Tax Queries` has the relation `OR`, where unchecked checkbox should give `AND` in my relation.

**What I expect overall to happen:**

When filterBoth is checked: filter for selected moods or genres, where one or more has to match the selected.

When filterBoth is unchecked: filter for selected moods or genres, where all selected moods and/or genres has to match.

**error.log**

```
///////////   HERE I UNCHECKED THE CHECKBOX, WHICH IS EXPECTED TO QUERY AND - CONSIDERED NOT WORKING   ///////////
filterBoth value received: false  <-- We confirm it's unchecked but received via AJAX
Selected Moods: Array
(
   [0] => Busy
   [1] => Dark
)

Selected Genres: Array
(
   [0] => Ballad
)

Tax Query: Array
(
   [relation] => OR  <-- We will, since it's false above, expect AND here
   [0] => Array
       (
           [taxonomy] => track-moods
           [field] => slug
           [terms] => Array
               (
                   [0] => Busy
                   [1] => Dark
               )

       )

   [1] => Array
       (
           [taxonomy] => track-genre
           [field] => slug
           [terms] => Array
               (
                   [0] => Ballad
               )

       )

)

Meta Query: Array
(
)

SQL Query: 
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS clk_3a02d77f58_posts.id
FROM   clk_3a02d77f58_posts
      LEFT JOIN clk_3a02d77f58_term_relationships
             ON ( clk_3a02d77f58_posts.id =
                  clk_3a02d77f58_term_relationships.object_id )
WHERE  1 = 1
      AND ( clk_3a02d77f58_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ( 110, 126 )
             OR clk_3a02d77f58_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ( 116 ) )
      AND (( clk_3a02d77f58_posts.post_type = 'track'
             AND ( clk_3a02d77f58_posts.post_status = 'publish'
                    OR clk_3a02d77f58_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
                    OR clk_3a02d77f58_posts.post_status = 'future'
                    OR clk_3a02d77f58_posts.post_status = 'draft'
                    OR clk_3a02d77f58_posts.post_status = 'pending'
                    OR clk_3a02d77f58_posts.post_status = 'private' ) ))
GROUP  BY clk_3a02d77f58_posts.id
ORDER  BY clk_3a02d77f58_posts.post_title ASC
LIMIT  0, 10 
               

///////////   HERE I CHECKED THE CHECKBOX, WHICH IS EXPECTED TO QUERY OR - CONSIDERED WORKING   ///////////

filterBoth value received: true  <-- We confirm it's checked and received via AJAX
Selected Moods: Array
(
   [0] => Busy
   [1] => Dark
)

Selected Genres: Array
(
   [0] => Ballad
)

Tax Query: Array
(
   [relation] => OR  <-- We correctly got OR here
   [0] => Array
       (
           [taxonomy] => track-moods
           [field] => slug
           [terms] => Array
               (
                   [0] => Busy
                   [1] => Dark
               )

       )

   [1] => Array
       (
           [taxonomy] => track-genre
           [field] => slug
           [terms] => Array
               (
                   [0] => Ballad
               )

       )

)

Meta Query: Array
(
)

SQL Query:
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS clk_3a02d77f58_posts.id
FROM   clk_3a02d77f58_posts
      LEFT JOIN clk_3a02d77f58_term_relationships
             ON ( clk_3a02d77f58_posts.id =
                  clk_3a02d77f58_term_relationships.object_id )
WHERE  1 = 1
      AND ( clk_3a02d77f58_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ( 110, 126 )
             OR clk_3a02d77f58_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ( 116 ) )
      AND (( clk_3a02d77f58_posts.post_type = 'track'
             AND ( clk_3a02d77f58_posts.post_status = 'publish'
                    OR clk_3a02d77f58_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
                    OR clk_3a02d77f58_posts.post_status = 'future'
                    OR clk_3a02d77f58_posts.post_status = 'draft'
                    OR clk_3a02d77f58_posts.post_status = 'pending'
                    OR clk_3a02d77f58_posts.post_status = 'private' ) ))
GROUP  BY clk_3a02d77f58_posts.id
ORDER  BY clk_3a02d77f58_posts.post_title ASC
LIMIT  0, 10
```

**My function:**

```
function filter_music_list() {
    global $wpdb;

    $selectedMoods = isset($_POST['moods']) ? $_POST['moods'] : array();
    $selectedGenres = isset($_POST['genres']) ? $_POST['genres'] : array();
    $selectedEnergies = isset($_POST['energies']) ? $_POST['energies'] : array();
    $filterBoth = isset($_POST['filterBoth']) ? $_POST['filterBoth'] : false;   <-- We receive filterBoth here, which is our checkbox 
    $sortOrder = isset($_POST['sort']) ? $_POST['sort'] : null;
    $vocals = isset($_POST['vocal']) ? $_POST['vocal'] : array();
    $bpm_values = get_bpm_range();
    $minBpm = $bpm_values['min_bpm'];
    $maxBpm = $bpm_values['max_bpm'];

    // Get page number from Ajax
    if (isset($_POST['pageNumber'])) {
        $page_number = $_POST['pageNumber'];
    } else {
        $page_number = 1;
    }

    $posts_per_page = 10;
    $offset = ($page_number - 1) * $posts_per_page;
    $metaQuery = array();
    $order = 'DESC';
    $orderBy = 'date';    

    // Sorting logic
    switch ($sortOrder) {
        case "Newest":
            $order = 'DESC';
            $orderBy = 'date';
            break;
        case "Popular":
            $order = 'DESC';
            $orderBy = 'meta_value_num';
            $metaQuery[] = array(
                'key' => 'play_count',
            );
            break;
        case "A-Z":
            $order = 'ASC';
            $orderBy = 'title';
            break;
        case "Low BPM":
            $order = 'ASC';
            $orderBy = 'meta_value_num';
            $metaQuery[] = array(
                'key' => 'bpm',
            );
            break;
        case "High BPM":
            $order = 'DESC';
            $orderBy = 'meta_value_num';
            $metaQuery[] = array(
                'key' => 'bpm',
            );
            break;
        case "Low Energy":
            $order = 'ASC';
            $orderBy = 'meta_value_num';
            $metaQuery[] = array(
                'key' => 'energy',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            );
            break;
        case "High Energy":
            $order = 'DESC';
            $orderBy = 'meta_value_num';
            $metaQuery[] = array(
                'key' => 'energy',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            );
            break;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['filterBoth'])) {   <-- We confirm that it is checked, and attempt to act accordingly. I suspect it fails here.
        // Prepare tax_query for filtering by moods and genres.
        $taxQuery = array('relation' => 'OR');
        if (!empty($selectedMoods)) {
            $taxQuery[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'track-moods',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $selectedMoods,
            );
        }

        if (!empty($selectedGenres)) {
            $taxQuery[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'track-genre',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $selectedGenres,
            );
        }
    } else {
        // Prepare tax_query for filtering by moods and genres.
        $taxQuery = array('relation' => 'AND');
        if (!empty($selectedMoods)) {
            $taxQuery[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'track-moods',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $selectedMoods,
                'operator' => $filterBoth ? 'IN' : 'AND'  // Choose operator based on filterBoth
            );
        }

        if (!empty($selectedGenres)) {
            $taxQuery[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'track-genre',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $selectedGenres,
                'operator' => $filterBoth ? 'IN' : 'AND'  // Choose operator based on filterBoth
            );
        }
    }

    if (!empty($selectedEnergies)) {
        $metaQuery[] = array(
            'key' => 'energy',
            'value' => $selectedEnergies,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        );
    }

    if (!empty($vocals)) {
        $metaQuery[] = array(
            'key' => 'vocal',
            'value' => $vocals,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        );
    }

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'track',
        'tax_query' => $taxQuery,
        'meta_query' => $metaQuery,
        'order' => $order,
        'orderby' => $orderBy,
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'offset' => $offset,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        $index = 0;
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            $setId = "set-" . time() . "-" . $index;
            $index++;

            echo '<div id="' . $setId . '" class="set">';

            get_template_part('components/track', 'music');

            echo '</div>';
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        echo 'No tracks found.';
    }

    // Total number of pages.
    $total_pages = $query->max_num_pages;

    // Current page number.
    $current_page = max(1, $page_number);

    // Base URL.
    $base_url = get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%';

    // Format of the page number. 
    $format = '?paged=%#%';

    // Set up paginate_links args.
    $pagination_args = array(
        'base' => $base_url,
        'format' => $format,
        'current' => $current_page,
        'total' => $total_pages,
        'prev_text' => __('&laquo; Prev'),
        'next_text' => __('Next &raquo;'),
        'type' => 'array'
    );

    // Generate paginate links.
    $page_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);\

    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_music_list', 'filter_music_list');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_music_list', 'filter_music_list');
```